# ImDisk: Create physical memory drive (not virtual memory drive) from command-line

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, virtual-memory, ramdisk

I'm using [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) to create a virtual drive in Windows 7. I use it as a temporary drive for documents, and it will be created every time the computer/windows restarts. This is working okay; however, I want to create the drive in physical memory instead of virtual memory.

In the configuration tab of Windows there is the 'ImDisk Virtual Disk Driver'. With this tool it is possible to create virtual disks in physical memory (see also image below), but the command-line version doesn't have a physical memory option or I can't figure out.

[image: Physilcal memory option in ImDisk Virtual Disk Driver]

Is it possible to create virtual disks in physical memory at the command line?

This is the command-line batch code that I currently using:

```
imdisk -a -s 512M -m Z: -p "/fs:ntfs /v:RAMDISK /A:512 /q /c /y"
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add parameter: -o awe

From: http://reboot.pro/topic/2148-news/page-3 Posted 28 March 2013 - 06:50 PM

Answer (score 5):

I wanted this on a server where permissions are a bit more complex, so here's the full command line for getting a physical RAM disk setup with ImDisk, creating a directory (so you can assign more complex permissions - there are limitations on full drive access), and assigning modify permissions to a group by its name.

```
imdisk -a -o awe -s 512M -m R: -p "/fs:ntfs /q /y"
cd R:
R:
mkdir r
icacls "R:\r" /grant Web:(OI)(CI)M
```

So it's saying to:

- `-a`: Make a virtual disk
- `-o awe`: In physical RAM
- `-s 512M`: 512 MB in size
- `-m R:`: Named R
- `-p...`: Tells it to format the disk with default parameters, quietly.

It switches to R, makes the dir `r`, and then `icacls` grants permissions to the group "Web" (if you wanted a user, just use their name here instead, no syntax difference), `(OI)(CI)` every file and folder inside should inherit this permission `M` Modify, which is read, list, write, create/delete/modify.